# Jquery change opacity of div on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, opacity

I've read various questions about this matter but I didn't found a solution for my particular case.
I need to change opacity of the thumbUp and thumbDown divs when they are clicked. Why does my code not work?

Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="foto">
        <img src="images/feu.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="descrizione">
        <p class="title">Feu d'artifice</p>
        <p>Giacomo Balla<br>
           1916-1917<br>
        </p>
        <div id="likeButtons">
            <p>Ti piace quest'opera?</p>
            <img id="thumbUp" src="images/thumbup.png">
            <img id="thumbDown" src="images/thumbdown.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pulsanteOpera" class="pulsante" style="padding: 30px 20px 0 0;float:right;">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>    
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#likeButtons{
position:relative;
right:-50%;
width:500px;
overflow:hidden;
font-weight:300;
margin-bottom:50px;
} 

#likeButtons p{
float:left;
}

#likeButtons img{
width:10%;
margin-bottom:30px;
padding-left:10px;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
}

#thumbUp,#thumbDown{
opacity:0.6;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#pulsanteOpera').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('pulsante').toggleClass('pulsanteRimuovi');
        });
    $('#thumbDown').click(function(){
            if($(this).css('opacity')==0.6)
        $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
        else
        $(this).css('opacity','0.6');
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: instead of checking for value from CSS property, you should just add/remove a class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest (though this is very similar to Suganthan's answer) using `toFixed()` as well as `parseFloat()`, which first parses the string-value held as the current value of `opacity`, and abbreviates that value from the unpredictably (cross-browser) long value of *almost* `0.6` to one decimal place:

```
$('#thumbDown, #thumbUp').click(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', function(i,o){
        return parseFloat(o).toFixed(1) === '0.6' ? 1 : 0.6;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/).

In preference to the above solution, though, I'd suggest instead using specific classes to toggle the opacity, rather than having to parse the the CSS property-values themselves, using the following:

```
$('#thumbDown, #thumbUp').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('faded opaque');
});
```

Coupled with the (additional) CSS:

```
.faded {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.opaque {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

(Also, remove the `opacity: 0.6;` from the `#thumbUp`/`#thumbDown` buttons to allow this to work, and set the appropriate style on the elements to start with, I've *added* the class of `faded` to both).

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/1/).

To amend the latter approach to ensure that 'selecting' one element deselects the other:

```
$('#thumbDown, #thumbUp').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass('faded opaque');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/2/)

The above, of course, presumes that you've set the initial classes appropriately so that one has the `opaque` class and the other has the `faded` class; however, to simplify and use only *one* additional class:

```
$('#thumbDown, #thumbUp').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass('opaque');
});
```

CSS:

```
#thumbUp, #thumbDown {
    opacity: 0.6; /* restored the default opacity here */
    position: relative;
}
#thumbUp.opaque, #thumbDown.opaque {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/3/).

To address the most recent comment from the OP:

> The latest edit is not what I was looking for precisely, at the beginning the two `div`s have `opacity = 0.6`. if I click on [thumbUp] it becomes opaque, but if I click on thumbDown the opacity of thumbUp must change to `0.6` and thumbDown shall become opaque.

I'd suggest removing the `opaque` class from the `img` elements (contrary to my previous suggestion), and then using the following:

```
$('#thumbDown, #thumbUp').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('opaque').siblings('.opaque').removeClass('opaque');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/4/).

Comment: I'm using your solution now, can you help me implementing it to use in firefox?

Comment: It works with the ids, not with classes I think. I changed all back using ids for the divs and it's working, thanks ;)

Comment: @David Thomas +1 helped me a lot

Comment: I know it's not related to main question, but how can I make one of the two divs' opacity return to 0.6 if the other one is selected? Thanks ;)

Comment: The latest edit is not what I was looking for precisely, at the beginning the two divs have opacity = 0.6. if I click on thumUp it becomes opaque, but if I click on thumbDown the opacity of thumbUp must change to 0.6 and thumbDown shall become opaque...is it clear enough? :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously I don't know the reason, let me to find that but this is working

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#pulsanteOpera').click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('pulsante').toggleClass('pulsanteRimuovi');
    });
$('#thumbDown').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).css('opacity'))
       if(parseFloat($(this).css('opacity')).toFixed(1)==0.6)
            $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
        else
            $(this).css('opacity','0.6');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this works...why that strange value on opacity??

Comment: @The Condor let me check, in the console I got that strange value

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having trouble reading the `opacity` property correctly and this could change based on browser. Try.

```
.clicked {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

$('#thumbDown').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
}
```

Also, try making `.clicked` a priority by placing it at the bottom of your CSS and below `#thumbDown`.

Comment: Yea, I figured you would run into `id` being a priority over `class`