# How to change opacity on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I change the opacity of the label on click by another label. Here's a snippet of code:

```
<style>
.selected {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

var linktext = svg.selectAll('g.linklabelholder').data(force.links())
     linktext.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'linklabelholder')
        .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'linklabel')
    .style('fill','red')
    .style('font','10px')
    .text(function(d) { return d.name })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("click", function (d){
           d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("selected", true);
       });

var linktext_add = svg.selectAll('g.linklabelholder_add').data(force.links())
    linktext_add.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'linklabelholder_add')
    .attr('id', function(d) { return 'i'+ d.inn; })
    .attr('class', 'linklabel_add')
    .append('text')
    .style('fill','black')
    .style("font-size","10px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "right")
    .attr("dy", -16)
    .text(function(d) { return d.inn; });
```

How to make first opacity=0 and changed to opacity=1 on click and then on the second click again to opacity=0?

Comment: I am still newer to CSS but can you do some sort of `toggle()` on the opacity style? For most CSS elements, toggle() does a good job of on/off or show/hide  EDIT: Even found a JSFiddle that has a an opacity toggle for an image. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fVTeC/)

Comment: It seems to be using SVG's, I don't know if he could do that in a JS Fiddle, but I'd be interested in knowing if the answer is yes.

Comment: While the actual question and headline are very very brief the code example you give is very very bulky ... How about doing other readers looking for enlightenment a favor and improve your question a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familar with SVG or the syntax here, but as Austin suggested in the comments, something like this is what I usually do when I have something like this:

Styling and header vars:

```
<style>
.selected {
    opacity: 0;
}
.deselected {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>

var toggleSelected = true;
```

And then for your on click...

```
.on("click", function (d){
           if(toggleSelected == true) {
               d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("selected", true);
               toggleSelected = false;
           } else {
               d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("deselected", true);
               toggleSelected = true;
           } 
});
```

This is setting a toggleSelected Boolean and on the first click would be set to 0 and on the second click set back to one.

I don't know about the syntax, though.

EDIT:
Austin has also pointed out this answer, [Jquery change opacity of div on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163711/jquery-change-opacity-of-div-on-click).

Comment: Found a similar article as well, if you would like to include it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163711/jquery-change-opacity-of-div-on-click

Comment: Yep, it's working.I added two lines and everything worked as I need: `code .on("click", function (d){
           if(toggleSelected == true) {
               d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("deselected", false);
      d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("selected", true);
               toggleSelected = false;
           } else {
          d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("selected", false);
               d3.select("#i" + d.inn).classed("deselected", true);
               toggleSelected = true;
           } 
}); ` Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

With the `toggleClick` jQuery plugin, you can have as many callbacks as you need. So if two is the number of your callbacks, the first will be triggered on odd clicks while the second on even clicks:

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var methods = arguments, // store the passed arguments for future reference
        count = methods.length; // cache the number of methods 

    //use return this to maintain jQuery chainability
    return this.each(function(i, item){
        // for each element you bind to
        var index = 0; // create a local counter for that element
        $(item).click(function(){ // bind a click handler to that element
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this,arguments); // that when called will apply the 'index'th method to that element
            // the index % count means that we constrain our iterator between 0 and (count-1)
        });
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('.selector').toggleClick( funcA [,funcB] [,funcC] ....[,funcZZZ] );
```

Ref:

https://github.com/maniator/jQuery-toggleClick